# Panda Group by sum specific columns and keep other columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to do something which should be simple...
I have a dataframe and I am trying to group by a specific column, the output dataframe needs to keep one column and sum two others columns.
Below is an example:

df:

```
User  Col1ToSum  Col2ToSum   ColToKeep
ABC     10         440         1.015
ABC     15         410         1.015
ABC     15        -200         1.015
ABA     100        110         2.24 
ABA     80        -10          2.24
AAA     40         10          nan
AAA     20         10          nan
BBB     10         15          nan
XYZ     10         10          1.1
XYZ     10         10          1.5 (note the 'ColToKeep' is different for user XYZ)
```

Expected Output:

```
User  Col1ToSum  Col2ToSum   ColToKeep
ABC     45         650         1.015
ABA     180        100         2.24
AAA     60         20          nan
BBB     10         15          nan
XYZ     10         10          1.1
XYZ     10         10          1.5
```

I tried to do:

1. `df.groupby(['User', 'ColToKeep'], as_index=False).mean()`
   Unfortunately, it is removing any records where ColToKeep is nan and the two columns to sum are not sum.
2. `df.groupby(['User'], as_index=False)['Col1ToSum', 'Col2ToSum'].sum()`
   Unfortunately, it is removing 'ColToKeep' column in the output df
3. `df.groupby(['User', 'ColToKeep'], as_index=False)['Col1ToSum', 'Col2ToSum'].sum()` but same as point 1) it is removing records where ColToKeep is nan

The reason why I tried to group by User and ColToKeep is because I want to have 2 records if User is the same BUT ColToKeep is different.

I am not sure why the group by would remove nan values (maybe due to my lack of experience with panda...)

Would you be able to please help on the above or even explain why it is happening ?

Comment: It is problematic that there is two Users `XYZ`, you should consider adding a column `id` that has a unique value for each user to be able to differentiate between users.

Comment: Indeed, I can add a user id later on to my dataset. It is not yet required and to keep it simple, that's why I did not have one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas support missing values in `groupby` from `1.1` version, [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#allow-na-in-groupby-key).

First idea is create new helper column `new` with replace missing values to some string, e.g. `miss`, then grouping by `new` with aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), last remove helper level by first `reset_index`:

```
df = (df.assign(new= df['ColToKeep'].fillna('miss'))
       .groupby(['User', 'new'], sort=False)
       .agg({'Col1ToSum':'sum', 'Col2ToSum':'sum', 'ColToKeep':'first'})
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .reset_index())
print (df)
  User  Col1ToSum  Col2ToSum  ColToKeep
0  ABC         40        650      1.015
1  ABA        180        100      2.240
2  AAA         60         20        NaN
3  BBB         10         15        NaN
4  XYZ         10         10      1.100
5  XYZ         10         10      1.500
```

Another idea is replace back `miss` to `NaN`s:

```
df = (df.assign(ColToKeep = df['ColToKeep'].fillna('miss'))
       .groupby(['User', 'ColToKeep'], sort=False)[['Col1ToSum', 'Col2ToSum']].sum()
       .reset_index()
       .replace({'ColToKeep': {'miss':np.nan}}))
print (df)
  User  ColToKeep  Col1ToSum  Col2ToSum
0  ABC      1.015         40        650
1  ABA      2.240        180        100
2  AAA        NaN         60         20
3  BBB        NaN         10         15
4  XYZ      1.100         10         10
5  XYZ      1.500         10         10
```

Comment: I like the solution because it is short and precise, but a little bit of text explaining what and how you do it would be great for people to understand what exactly they are going to copy-paste from SO  ;)

Comment: @Cribber - Give me some time for description ;)

Comment: Yes I like this solution and make sense with the description now. I did not even know about the assign method. (Will be checking it in a min from doc). Thank you for your answer

Comment: @WilliamW - You are welcome, here is docs - [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change "ColToKeep" to a string, then use your code.

```
In : df['ColToKeep'] = df['ColToKeep'].astype(str)

In : df.groupby(['User','ColToKeep'], as_index=False).sum()
Out: 
  User ColToKeep  Col1ToSum  Col2ToSum
0  AAA       nan         60         20
1  ABA      2.24        180        100
2  ABC     1.015         40        650
3  BBB       nan         10         15
4  XYZ       1.1         10         10
5  XYZ       1.5         10         10
```

You can change the ColToKeep back to a float if necessary by:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['User','ColToKeep'], as_index=False).sum()

df1['ColToKeep'] = df1['ColToKeep'].astype(float)

print(df1)
  User  ColToKeep  Col1ToSum  Col2ToSum
0  AAA        NaN         60         20
1  ABA      2.240        180        100
2  ABC      1.015         40        650
3  BBB        NaN         10         15
4  XYZ      1.100         10         10
5  XYZ      1.500         10         10
```

Comment: This might work, but it feels very wrong to handle missing values as "nan"-Strings...

Comment: Just using it to group the values; it can be changed back after grouping, if desired.

Comment: Still feelds weird, but alright - can you please include this step in your solution to have a complete picture of what is necessary?

Comment: Hmm it did not work (I am getting an exception: "must be real number, not str" which I guess is because ColToKeep has been detected as a float column whereas we try to assign a string. I see what you are trying to do and indeed, I could have used something similar to this. Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Edited to show how to return the ColToKeep column back to float.

Comment: @WilliamW I'm not sure why this isn't working for you. You should be able to convert a float to a string using the command df['ColToKeep'] = df['ColToKeep'].astype(str)